# Picasso center image without resizing into ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, picasso

I've come across this simple problem with the `Picasso library`. I haven't find any way to put an image into `ImageView` center it like `android:ScaleType="center"` does without cropping. Do you have any ideas about how to solve this ? My problem is that I don't know at the runtime the height and width of the `BitMap` I download so I can't use `resize()` properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but for anyone who's looking for a solution :

```
Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(ImageURL)
    .fit()
    // call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
    .into(imageViewFit);
```

Comment: Hi Alok, I am actually looking for solution, but doing fit, it will resize the image. Sometimes, my image is only 32x32 pixels and I don't want it to be resized. Any idea?

Comment: Try not using any of the fit / centerInside / centerCrop calls. This is the official site : http://square.github.io/picasso/ ; if it doesn't work, may be imageview scaletype in xml try changing that.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ImageView` is fixed one dimension and flexible another dimension (ex. `android:width="match_parent"`, `android:height="wrap_content"`), you should be able to use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to get the `ImageView` to resize to display your image without cropping.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't solve my problem. I am downloading a lot of images into a pagerview with imageView inside. So I need to resize my photos to avoid memory problems

Answer (score 0):

i am not found fit to center without resizing,

```
 Picasso.get()
                        .load(source).resize(1650,700)
                        .centerCrop(Gravity.CENTER).into(imageView, new Callback()
```